# How to inject service into action in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, interface

I am interested if it is possible to inject custom services, which implement my interface into action. From the [symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html) it's not possible. To understand me properly let me show you an easy exmaple:

Les's imagine we have a controller C1 with has two actions: a1Action and a2Action. There is a service S1 which implement interface IS. Ok. 
And in a2Action I am planning to use this service. It was registered under "app.s1.service" name, so, as we know I can get this service by using the following command:

```
$this->get('app.s1.service');
```

By using some sort of third-party bundles, like [di-extra-bundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle) 
we can do it in other ways. Anyway. What bothers me is that I want to be sure, that if someday, someone crates a new service S2 and wants to change my service in a2Action, it won't break the whole application because of there is no appropriate method in S2, actually a new developer didn't implement my interface. And I don't want to inject this service into constructor, because in a1Action I don't use it. Like in Laravel, I want to have a possibility to inject inteface into my a2Action and get appropriate implementation.
I was playing round ControllerResolver, but it looks pretty complicated for this kind of issue. And I wanna avoid additional checks in my actions, something like that:

```
$s2 = $this->get('app.s2.service')
if (!$s2 instanceof IS) {
  // ... bla bla bla
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess that you could [define your controller as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) and then configure your service.yml to inject an instance of app.s2.service. Maybe it works as you desire. Obviously, you are not injecting it directly to the action, but you are injecting it into your controller (now it is a service) constructor.

Comment: @Muriano OP mentioned that he doesn't want to inject dependecies via constructor but directly to action method. That's the whole point of the question.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I understood it in a wrong way. Well, with this "update", I suppose you can make a little trick  and create a  [custom param converter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter) that returns to you an instance of your desire service. That's not the proper way to work with, but it would works fine.

Comment: You can try to use "Naked bundles" approach http://www.slideshare.net/matthiasnoback/the-naked-bundle-symfony-live-london-2014. So each action will be a separate controller and will hold only it's dependencies.

Comment: It's also possible to override the default controller resolver which, among other things, takes care of injecting method arguments.  But @DmitryGrachikov has the solution, move to one action per controller.  Once you take this step then many things become much cleaner.